# Convert API Syntax in node.js express to separate function to support multer on image file upload

Tags: node.js, express, crud, router, multer

I'm creating a generic CRUD class for a schema to automatically build the [ ***Create, Read, Update, Delete API functions*** ] and I have the following code and its working just fine but I want to add multer to the code below in order for it to allow uploading and retrieving of images for image fields.

```
const create = (req, res) => {
  .
  .
  .
};

const update = (req, res) => {
  .
  .
  .
};

router.post('/', create);
router.put('/:_id', update);
```

The example on multer - npm page is the following:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var router = express()
router.post('/create', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

How do i convert:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
```

to the syntax

```
    const create = (req, res) => {
      .
      .
      .
    };

    router.post('/', create);
```

on the syntax above what must I change to incorporate the ff:

```
upload.single('avatar')
```

Comment: `router.post('/', upload.single('avatar'), create)` wouldnt this simply pass the req.file to your create function? Meaning your `req` object will have a reference to that parameter

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way-

```
router.post('/', upload.single('avatar'), create);
```